# How to change the size of an emoji? | Discord.js

Tags: discord.js

Let me be more specific here. I'm making a Discord bot, and I made an `enlarge` command that basically enlarges any emoji provided (Basically, have it look bigger). So far, I've had it send the emoji as an image, but it's too small, and I want it to be bigger, so my question is, what do I have to add to change the size, or is there no way to do so. I'll leave the code that sends it below in case someone may need it. Thank you in advance.

```js
const parsedEmoji = Util.parseEmoji(emoji)
if(parsedEmoji.id) {
  const extension = parsedEmoji.animated ? ".gif" : ".png"
  const url = `https://cdn.discordapp.com/emojis/${parsedEmoji.id + extension}`
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [developer docs](https://discord.com/developers/docs/reference#image-formatting): Just add the `?size=<number>` querystring to change the size of the emoji. Example:

```
https://cdn.discordapp.com/emojis/${parsedEmoji.id + extension}?size=256
```

The size can be any power of two between 16 and 4096, so all the valid sizes are 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024, 2048, and 4096.